# convert hex Timestamp to readable date and time

Tags: c++, macos, outlook

I'm trying to understand how a binary file (.olk Outlook office 2016 for MAC) works.
I'm using a hex editor do this. I understand most of the file, however I am stuck with this timestamp problem. I am 100% sure that a part of this hex is the actual timestamp:

'00 00 00 5F BF 35 BE 41'

On screen, it outputs: 23 Jan 2017 10:04:39

'00 00 00 5F BF 35 BE 41' value is 4737282954089201664 according to little endian

'00 00 00 5F BF 35 BE 41' value is 411229863489 according to big endian

If i edit(modify) hex value 00 00 00 5F BF 35 BE 41 than i get Date and time which is 1 Jan 2001 05:30:00

Answer (score 2):

Your time stamp looks like a 64-bit floating point value stored little endian.

The number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001 as I write this is 511696145.577641, and the hex representation of that 64-bit double is 41be7fdd1193e048. Given your sample date was in Jan that seems about right.

**Addendum after Comments**

Reading your question the main issue appeared to be determining how the time stamp was being stored. My hypothesis was that it was a standard Mac/Cocoa floating point time interval. I tested that hypothesis using the following code:

```
union { double d; int64_t i; } di;
di.d = [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSLog(@"%f | %llx", di.d, di.i);
```

The `union` is an easy way to access the bits of a floating point value, and `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` gives the time in seconds since the Mac OS X/Cocoa epoch. This produced (when initially run) the values shown above. I'd proved my hypothesis.

If you wish to go the other way using the same technique you can use:

```
union { double d; int64_t i; } di;
di.i = 0x41BE35BF5F000000;
NSDate *stamp = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:di.d];
NSLog(@"%llx -> %@", di.i, stamp);
```

and this produces:

```
41be35bf5f000000 -> 2017-01-23 04:34:39 +0000
```

(This differs from the time you have, it looks like you are displaying the times as local in India while the above is displaying in UTC.)

If you wish to manipulate the time stamp in C(++), rather than Objective-C(++) or Swift and Cocoa, you can use the standard C library functions as long as you take into account the different epochs. Your time stamp is based on an epoch 1 Jan 2001, "Unix" time starts at 1 Jan 1970. To interpret your time stamp as a Unix time offset you must add the Unix time offset for 1 Jan 2001 00:00 UTC to it first, you can generate that value using the C routines.

If you are reading the bytes for your value out of a buffer you *can* just cast the buffer address to a `double *` and indirect, as the Intel cpu supports misaligned access, e.g. something like:

```
double timeOffset = *(double *)&buf[Time_STAMP_OFFSET];
```

**However** for robust code you should use something like `memcpy()` to copy the bytes into the `double` variable, which will survive changing to a CPU which doesn't support misaligned access. You might also wish to add a call to a library function to convert little-endian to host byte order, to be robust against CPU endianness.

HTH

Comment: Hi CRD, 

How did you convert 1 January 2001 to decimal and this decimal to hex.
Kindly explain.

Comment: To confirm my hypothesis I used Apple's `NSDate` class (Objective-C or Swift) and its method `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` which returns the number of seconds as a `double` (aka `NSTimeInterval` in this case). That was displayed using the format `%f`. To quickly show its hex I used a `union` of `double` and `int64_f` and the format `%llx`. Whole thing was 3 lines of code.

Comment: You can use standard C library routines to work convert between seconds and date strings. You just need to note that the "Unix" epoch (1970) and the Mac one (2001) and add/subtract the appropriate offset when converting to/from the value in your Outlook file.

Comment: Hi CRD, Thanks for reply. Which three lines you have used. Can you tell me step. I mean first need to copy hex value(00 00 00 5F BF 35 BE 41) to a union whose data members are double and int64_f . Thanks

Comment: @qtsoft - added my test code and some further comment, HTH

Comment: Hi CRD,
i appreciate you.
41be35bf5f000000 is displaying 2017-01-23 04:34:39 +0000  according to UTC. But if i want to convert it according to my displaying output(2017-01-23 10:04:39) then need to get local time zone of that system and need to add or subtract UTC offset for example if at  my system time zone is United States (most of Arizona) then need to subtract UTC offset 07:00 from output time got from coresponding hex time stamp.

Comment: @qtsoft - Time offsets are stored relative to UTC regardless of the local time zone. Displaying the local time is an issue of formatting. Using Cocoa you can use the `NSDateFormatter` and `NSTimeZone` classes, there are also C library functions you can look up. If you get stuck search SO for answers, formatting dates and times is a common topic.

Comment: OK CDR, I will try myself. but i want to know that  UTC offset can be get from the hex timestamp

Comment: @qtsoft - The code in the answer shows you how to get obtain the UTC offset (the hex bytes *are* the UTC offset of course, the code just reads them as the `double` they really are). If you are looking for the local time offset relative to the UTC then that may not be in the Outlook file at all, rather Outlook will just display times relative to where it is running.

Answer (score 2):

Building on CRD's good (and upvoted) answer, and your comment concerning 1 Jan 2001 05:30:00, and assuming that you meant when you modify the hex value, it is to all zeroes, and using this [free, open-source date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "date.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    std::string s = {'\x0', '\x0', '\x0', '\x5f', '\xbf', '\x35', '\xbe', '\x41'};
    std::istringstream file{s};
    union
    {
        double d;
        unsigned char b[8];
    };
    for (auto& c : b)
        file >> c;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    constexpr auto epoch = sys_days{jan/1/2001} + 5h + 30min;
    sys_seconds datetime = epoch + seconds{static_cast<std::int64_t>(d)};
    std::cout << datetime << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2017-01-23 10:04:39
```

Explanation:

This field is the binary representation of a double on macOS (and Windows).  I have faked a file containing this field in the variable `file` above.  To read it into a double I'm using a not-quite standard trick of the union of a `double` and array of `unsigned char`, reading into the array, and then using the `double`.

This double is the number of seconds since 2001-01-01 05:30:00.  The date library is first used to form a `std::chrono::time_point` epoch with this value.  Then the `double` is cast to a 64bit signed integral type, and that is further converted to `std::chrono::seconds`, and then added to the `epoch` to form a new `std::chrono::time_point` which has seconds precision and corresponds to the value you report.  This date library has a streaming operator for this `std::chrono::time_point` for easy viewing.

If you would rather write your own calendrical computations, this date library is based on the algorithms [found here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html).

If you would like to break `datetime` into integral field types representing year, month, day, etc.:

```
sys_days sd = floor<days>(datetime);
year_month_day ymd = sd;
auto tod = make_time(datetime - sd);
int y = int{ymd.year()};        // 2017
int m = unsigned{ymd.month()};  // 1
int d = unsigned{ymd.day()};    // 23
int h = tod.hours().count();    // 10
int M = tod.minutes().count();  // 4
int s = tod.seconds().count();  // 39
```